# Why won't Groovy/Grape resolve artifacts from Maven Central?

Tags: maven, groovy, maven-central, groovy-grape

With a fresh download of Groovy 2.1.9, I create:

```
// Test.Groovy
@Grab('commons-io:commons-io:1.2')
import org.apache.commons.io.CopyUtils
println "Resolved!"
```

Then I try running

```
$ ./groovy-2.1.9/bin/groovy Test.groovy
```

which fails with

```
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- 
[download failed: commons-io#commons-io;1.2!commons-io.jar]
```

#### The artifact is [listed](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/commons-io/commons-io/1.2) in maven central, downloadable [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/commons-io-1.2.jar)

For what it's worth, various local files are created in:

`~/.groovy/grapes/commons-io/commons-io`

### I'd very much appreciate ideas on how to debug or "resolve"!

#### Update

If I create a new user on my system (with no dotfiles in her homedir), this **works**. So I've got some user-specific config that's breaking things. I've tried deleting `~/.groovy`, `~/.m2` and `~/.ivy` to no avail. What else could it be?

Comment: Groovy is the most indeterministic environment I've used in a long time...  Did you ever solve the reason behind this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Not clear what's wrong...

```
$ groovy -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true test
Resolving dependency: commons-io#commons-io;1.2 {default=[default]}
Preparing to download artifact commons-io#commons-io;1.2!commons-io.jar
Downloaded 64 Kbytes in 323ms:
  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-io#commons-io;1.2!commons-io.jar (306ms)
Resolved!
```

To dig some more you can enable debug as follows:

```
groovy -Divy.message.logger.level=4 test
```

Comment: Adding a ~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml seems to have helped -- but I can't figure out why the defaults weren't working (as they do when I create a new user).

Answer (score 0):

I am running Groovy 2.2.2 and have the same problem. I solved by deleting `~/.ivy2`.