# Groovy grape not resolving artifacts in Maven central

Tags: maven, groovy, ivy, groovy-grape

Fresh install of Groovy and for some reason it isn't pulling artifacts from Maven central:

```
$ grape resolve org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient 4.2.1
Error in resolve:
    Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar, download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1!httpcore.jar, download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1!commons-logging.jar]
```

Complete `-d` debug log:
https://gist.github.com/mrobinet/a86073e35771cab55665

Environment:

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.4 JVM: 1.7.0_79 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

The artifacts clearly exist:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/

Things I've tried:

- Adding Maven Central to ~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml
- grape -r https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 resolve org.apache.httpcomponents httpclient 4.2.1

Viewing the debug output, it doesn't even appear to be requesting it from central.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993227/why-wont-groovy-grape-resolve-artifacts-from-maven-central, but it is a year old with no answer.

Comment: Can you post the `-d` output in a gist?

Comment: Great idea! Edited to add a link to the gist: https://gist.github.com/mrobinet/a86073e35771cab55665

Comment: Hm, I don't see it going out to any internet repository at all. It only checks your ivy caches and maven caches. Are you sure you are running with the default ivy config?

Comment: Yeah. The `~/.ivy` directory does not even exist and no `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` either.

Comment: I tried this locally (albeit on Windows 7 with Oracle Java 1.7.0_72 and Groovy 2.4.4) and everything worked (with and without `~/.m2`). I added `-d` and then compared my output to your gist. I couldn't spot a difference that might be significant. I don't have `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml`. I even tried without `~/.groovy` as well. I am not using `gvm` (your gist suggests that you are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into this again and was able to figure out the issue. I ended up filing a bug with Groovy: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8655

The problem occurs when you have only a POM file for the artifact in your Maven local repository (no jar file).